# Show default language message if message key is not found in language file

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

In my Codeigniter project, I am integrating multilanguage support. For this I have defined a helper class *lang_helper.php* with following code.

```
function lang_dropdown()
{
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->load->database();
    $sql = "select language from languages";
    $q = $ci->db->query($sql);
    $data=$q->result();
    $list=array();
    $list['']= 'Language';      
     foreach($data as $type )
     {
        $list[$type->language]= $type->language;      
     }
    return $list;
}
```

and I have created individual language files in *application/language* folder (For example, for english language I have created message keys and values in *application/language/english/message_lang.php* file).

Now in controller functions, I have included the following lines and passed these to view file for showing the language dropdown.

In controller,

```
$data['dropdown'] = lang_dropdown();  // multilanguage dropdown list
$data['language']=$this->session->userdata('site_language');
```

and in view,

```
$js = 'id="langdrop" onChange="changelanguage(\''.base_url().'\')"';
echo form_dropdown('langdrop', $dropdown,$language,$js);
```

which displays the dropdown like,

```
<select name="langdrop" id="langdrop" onchange="changelanguage('http://192.168.1.150/workspace/teshot/')">
<option value="">Language</option>
<option value="chinese">chinese</option>
<option value="dutch">dutch</option>
<option value="english" selected="selected">english</option>
</select>
```

and my js function is:

```
function changelanguage(baseurl)
{
    var lang=$("#langdrop").val();
    window.location=baseurl+"index.php/index/language/"+lang;
}
```

and I display the multilanguage message as `lang('messagekey')`. Everything is working fine now.

Now my requirement is, if there is no keys/values corresponding to selected language in the language file, then it should show message from default language file.

ie, I have a message in *application/language/english/message_lang.php* file as,

```
$lang['hourago']='hour ago';
```

So for displaying this in view file, I will write like this `lang('hourago')`. If there is not such an entry in file corresponding to french language (in *application/language/french/message_lang.php* file), then it should display the message from my default language (suppose if my default language is English, then it should display the value `hour ago` ).

I have created a file *LanguageLoader.php* in *application/hooks* folder.

```
class LanguageLoader
{
    public function load_language()
    {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->helper('language');
        $ci->load->library('session');
        $language= $ci->session->userdata('site_language');
        if ($language)
        { 
            $ci->lang->load('message', $language);
        }
        else
        {
            $ci->lang->load('message', 'english');
        }
    }
}
```

and also have enabled hooks in config folder, *hooks.php*

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class' => 'LanguageLoader',
    'function' => 'load_language',
    'filename' => 'LanguageLoader.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => array()
);
```

How this is possible? Can anyone help me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit and show the functions changelanguage and lang code?

Comment: load english first as default and then apply the other language to that, if the other language doesn't have an entry the english will be there by default

Comment: @dops..can you make it more clear..

Comment: @dops..can you help me to solve this..I am not getting how to implement this?

Comment: @Jenz sorry got distracted . the same way you load your language on the dropdown change.  You just do it onload of the page and default to english.

Comment: @dops..I have given the default language as English in the config file

Comment: @Jenz could you post the relevant code for changelanguage() please

Comment: @dops..Updated my question.